# How can I save each image to a folder from this array on jupyter notebook?

Tags: save, numpy-ndarray

I have an array full of 25 images, with a shape of (25, 64, 128, 1). I'm trying to save each image as jpg into a folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install PIL using `pip install Pillow`. Let's assume `arr` is the array of shape (25, 64, 128, 1).

```py
from PIL import Image

for i in range(arr.shape[0])
    im = Image.fromarray(arr[i, :, :, 0])
    im.save(f"image_{i}.jpeg")
```